# friendly_id on belongs_to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, friendly-id

I have a devise `User` model and a Profile model which `belongs_to` the `User`

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

The `User` model has a added column called `name` which stores the users name.

Im using [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) and want to apply it to the Profile model like so:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

But rather than create another column in the `Profile` model called `name`, i want to use the `User` model column `name` here, which the profile `belongs_to`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer from `friendly_id` repository [owner](https://github.com/norman) to a similar question from [Github issue](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/558#issuecomment-44527493):

> Sorry, not going to do this. This was how FriendlyId 3.x and below worked. If you have very large tables, performance is significantly worse with the slug in a separate table.

So it a nutshell, the slug must be placed in the same table.